# How to handle Siri interruption on Apple TV

Tags: tvos, siri

I'm looking for a way to handle Siri interruptions on the AppleTV.

According to this guide: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/responding_to_audio_session_interruptions it should be possible to get notifications of an audio session interruption, but this doesn't seem to work.

I have tried

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(handleInterruption(_:)),
        name: .AVAudioSessionInterruption,
        object: nil)
```

The callback never occurs.

What i would like is to pause video while the user is using Siri and then resume when they have finished.

Answer (score 0):

```
internal func registerToHandleInterruptions() {
    // When Siri interrupts playback a UIApplicationWillResignActive notification will be triggered
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(handleInterruption(_:)),
        name: .UIApplicationWillResignActive,
        object: nil)
    // When Siri returns control to the app, a UIApplicationDidBecomeActive notification is fired
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(handleActive(_:)),
        name: .UIApplicationDidBecomeActive,
        object: nil)
}
```

After much searching, i've figured out the following:

- On tvOS it doesn't seem like a Siri interruption fires a `.AVAudioSessionInterruption` notification, despite what the official documentation says. (outdated?, not applicable to tvOS?)
- A Siri interruption is actually sending the app to the background, so it is possible to react by watching `.UIApplicationWillResignActive` and `.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive` instead.